# How do I get the Ubuntu Unity Launcher to work on a Bootable USB?

Tags: unity, usb

I am having trouble getting the Ubuntu Unity Launcher to work on the Bootable USB key that I have.

Here is my desktop for reference just to show that the unity launcher is not listed among the icons on the side:

[image]

I have already tried these commands with no success:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
sudo apt-get update
```

here are the results of this:

[image]

[image]

I am not sure why the  unity launcher is not working for me any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the first screenshot, it seems you aren't connected to internet (Since there's neither WiFi nor wired logo). You need to be connected to internet to download and install Unity desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: In order to install `ubuntu-unity-desktop` package, you need to have an active internet connection.

The package is under "universe" repository

```
Exact hits
Package ubuntu-unity-desktop

    bionic (18.04LTS) (metapackages): The Ubuntu Unity desktop system [universe]
```

Run the below command to add the universe repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then install the package

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

Once the package is Installed, you can't choose the `unity` session from the login screen. The ⚙️ icon which is used to change desktop environment only appears at password screen in GDM.

To add password for live user:

Run:

```
gnome-control-center user-accounts
```

Add new password after clicking on "None".

[image]

Then logout using the drop down menu in the upper right corner

[image]

Click on the gear icon (⚙️) to Desktop Environment

[image]

You'll see Unity Desktop after logging in

[image]

Comment: This would work only if OP is having internet connection :)

Comment: Why add new user when you can add password for existing "Live Session User" and get prompt for changing DE.

Comment: I've edited your answer and removed adding new user. Moreover since nowadays `add-apt-repository` auto triggers `apt update`, therefore, I removed that also. I've also redacted the example, since it ain't required IMO. But if you feel that my edits aren't justified, feel free to roll back/add things.

Comment: Sounds neat and clean.. Your edits r final.. Thanks !!!